# Rename a list of files

Tags: files-and-directories, file-transfer

I need to rename a list of files .bmp having name like 1.bmp, 2.bmp,...,155.bmp. I want to get a list of files having the same number of digits in name like 001.bmp,002.bmp....,155.bmp.

I am trying like this but I need just a bit of help

```
filesnames =  FileNames["/Users/xxxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/ xxxxx/images/*.bmp"];
filesnamessorted = SortBy[filesnames, StringLength];

renamesfiles = Table[RenameFile[filesnames[[i]], "/Users/xxxx/xx/xx/xx/xxxxxx/" <> 
                     ToString[i] <> ".bmp"], {i, 1, Length[filesnames]}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just apply string replacement to the list of files.  No need to sort.  Example:

```
replacer = 
 ReleaseHold@
   StringReplace[#, 
    RegularExpression["(\\d+)"] -> 
     IntegerString[Hold@ToExpression["$1"], 10, 3]] &
replacer /@ {"9.bmp", "10.bmp"}
```